# SQL syntax that will create a flag that lags based on ID and Marker

Tags: sql

I have a table of events that is structured similar to the attached image, where there is an ID for an item, followed by a marker for a different event, a sequence variable for the number of events within the marker, as well as whether the sequence of event is the last one in the marker.

I was hoping to create another flag that would basically indicate that the item ID appears in a new marker but am having a hard time wrapping my head around a good approach on this.

Wondering if there is something to do with lag() or a case when but could use help.

The image below has what my desired output would be which would be the DesiredFlag variable.

[image]

Comment: Most modern DBMSes support LAG() window function

Comment: That was my thinking, but was wondering if there is a way to use CASE WHEN() with LAG() so that instead of having it be Marker + 1 (which will be hard to analyze in the actual table) the marker will just be a simple 1,0.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the flag using this SQL:

```
SELECT id, marker,
    CASE 
        WHEN LAG(marker) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY marker) != marker 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END AS flag
FROM table
ORDER BY id, marker;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read your description correctly, (ID,Marker,Seq) increases along the process, and when ID increases by +1, the previous row's desire flag become 1.
Therefore, the logic can be written by SQL [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html).

Assuming you are using PostgreSQL, see the following code as an example

```
SELECT
   ID,
   Mark,
   Seq,
   lastSeq,
   -- when LEAD() a.k.a. next row's id is NOT the same ID, DesiredFlag become 1
   WHEN COALESCE(LEAD(ID) over (order by id, Mark, Seq) != ID, TRUE) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
   END DesiredFlag
FROM
   table
```